# EditText.setText()/getText() appears to be too slow to be used in TextWatcher

Tags: android

I have a TextWatcher that adds a dollar sign in front of an EditText value (it's a price field). Everything works fine except that if you type two first digits fast enough, the second digit won't appear. Once you past the first two digits it's all fine. If you type them slowly (almost a second in between) it also works fine.
Here is the TextWatcher code I am using:

```
@AfterTextChange(R.id.add_itemPrice) // android annotations way
void addDollar(Editable e) {
    if (priceFieldBeingModified) {
        return;
    }
    if (!e.toString().startsWith(CURRENCY_SYMB)) {
        priceFieldBeingModified = true;
        String newValue = CURRENCY_SYMB + e;
        priceField.setText(newValue);
        if (priceField.getSelectionStart() == 0) {
            // move the cursor to the end
            priceField.setSelection(priceField.getText().length());
        }
        priceFieldBeingModified = false;
    }
}
```

priceField EditText has fixed layout_width/layout_height (in dp). From what I can gather, setText()/getText() are just too expensive but I don't know how to avoid them in this case.
`priceField.getText().insert(0, CURRENCY_SYMB)` doesn't do anything for some reason.

**EDIT:
Looks like the problem only happens on Android 4.3 (or an Xperia Z phone). Tried a 4.1 phone - works like a charm.**

Any suggestions would be appreciated, I am out of ideas with this one!

Comment: Regarding your last attempt: `priceField.getText()` doesn't automatically update the EditText if you alter the String that you get from `getText()`. You need `setText()` for that.

Comment: ok, true. Unfortunatelly insert() doesn't move the cursor automatically as I hoped, so that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Tried to turn off the filter on that field - didn't help. Started getting desperate, tried the same code I have without Android Annotations - no luck either :)

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(s.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {

    }

    else if (!s.toString().startsWith("$")) {
        priceFieldBeingModified = true;
        String newValue = "$" + s;
        e.setText(newValue);
        if (e.getSelectionStart() == 0) {
        // move the cursor to the end
        e.setSelection(e.getText().length());
    }
    priceFieldBeingModified = false;
}
```

It checks if string is not null and it doesn't start with "$", then it adds "$" at start and moves cursor to end.

Comment: The only meaningful difference from my code is checking is Editable is empty in the beginning? Or am missing something?

Comment: `priceField.setText(newValue);` is replace by `e.setText(newValue);`. Did you try this? I am checking null so it doesn't keep adding $ when I clear edittext. @Leo test once.I tested

Comment: e is my EditText, @ThaMe90

Comment: priceField is my EditText, i.e. the same as your "e". So no change?

Comment: Then you must be doing some other mistake as this works fine for me @Leo All the best for figuring it out :)

Comment: Could be a difference in the layout then. Shouldn't, since EditText has the fixed width but who knows. I'll play with that...

Comment: No, that's no the layout. Even with a simplest layout possible the second digit doesn't show.

Comment: What happens when you add just 5? What is the current behavior? @Leo

Comment: And can you once try using simple `e.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {});` instead of this Annotations method? @Leo

Comment: Yes I tried addTextChangedListener - same problem. But looks like it happens only on Xperia Z (or android 4.3) though, tried a different phone it works fine. Hmm...

Comment: @Leo okay. congrats :)

Comment: @Leo did you try adding text in `onTextChanged` instead of `afterTextChanged`?

Comment: Documentation states you shouldn't be using onTextChanged to change the value. That's what afterTextChanged is for. And nothing point to this being a problem anyway. getText()/setText()/setSelection() - one of those misbehaves (too slow) in Android 4.3